# Как в VSCode перейти к изменениям внутри файла?

Tags: visual-studio-code

У меня открыт DiffViewer, показывающий изменения. Я хочу перейти к файлу, в котором были изменения. Но так, чтобы курсор/вид стоял на изменениях, а не наверху файла. Т.е. если изменения на строке 42, то и открыть должно там, как сделано в нормальных IDE. Можно ли это настроить или поставить расширение какое-нибудь?

P.S. для локальных изменений сейчас работает как надо, но вот для изменений в прошлых коммитах - нет (даже при том, что номер строки не поменялся за это время).